# Why there is not runClient?

Tags: eclipse, minecraft-forge

Hi StackOverflow I was using Eclipse to create my first Minecraft mod, and when I was ready to test it (from Eclipse), the java option (called runClient in the video I was watching) did not appear.

[image: 1]

I'm new to this theme and was looking forward to making a mod until I read that I might not be able to use that option.

Comment: It is up to you to create what is needed in the Run > Run Configurations dialog. I don't know exactly what is needed for Minecraft.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot from the video showing what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

`runClient` is a configuration from the default Forge `build.gradle` file.

1. Go to the [Forge downloads page](https://files.minecraftforge.net/).
2. Find the version of Minecraft your mod is for.
3. Download the MDK (Mod Development Kit) - **Note**: Not the installer or changelog.
4. Extract the MDK zip file and find the `runClient` configuration there.
5. You should copy the entire `build.gradle` into your project and modify it to your needs.

Take the time to read the Forge Documentation, starting with '[Getting Started](https://docs.minecraftforge.net/en/latest/gettingstarted/)'. These docs are short but provide good information to get you going.